# Have I made a mistake with my WordPress pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

The pagination on a site I am working on is not working; I really can't work out why as it is the same as the other templates within the site. I am wondering if there is a problem with the loop, perhaps where I have specified what category I want it to pull.

This is the page I am having trouble with:

```
<div class="container content newspage">
<div class="two_third newsarticles">
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=388' ); while($catquery->have_posts()) :  $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content-archive', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<nav id="nav-below">
<div class="nav-previous">
<?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'anariel' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div class="nav-next">
  <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;  </span>', 'anariel' ) ); ?>
</div>
</nav>
<!-- end nav-below -->
</div>
<!-- end two_third -->
<div class="sidebar">

    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Default Sidebar') ) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

 </div>

</div>
<!-- end container -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The template that does work correctly is here:

```
<div class="container content newspage">
<div class="two_third newsarticles">
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
<nav id="nav-below">
<div class="nav-previous">
  <?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'anariel' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div class="nav-next">
  <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;  </span>', 'anariel' ) ); ?>
 </div>
 </nav>
 <!-- end nav-below -->
 <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
 <!-- end two_third -->
 <aside>
 <div class="one_third lastcolumn newssidebar">
   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
 </div>
 </aside>
 </div>
 <!-- end container -->
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have tried copying this over into the template that doesn't work without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a custom query, you have to add the page number to your arguments.

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php 
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $catquery = new WP_Query( array('cat' => 388, 'paged' => $paged) ); while($catquery->have_posts()) :  $catquery->the_post(); ?>
```

You should also pass the number of pages to `get_next_posts_link`

```
next_posts_link(  __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'anariel' ), $catquery->max_num_pages );
```

Comment: This does work thank you. However, it seems to break my loop. How should I be adding the first section in?

Comment: Thank you that was helpful and worked. It's a shame as when you click on "older posts" it reloads the page with the same posts, it doesn't retrieve the old ones. Will research and see if I can fix it. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I fixed this by changing "page" to "paged". Thanks so much for your help mtinsley :-)